# How can i make this more user friendly?

Tags: python

```
print ("Address book")
print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print ("Welcome to your address book")

yn = ""

while yn != "n":
    yn = input ("Would you like to search for a user? (Y/N) ")

    if yn == "y":
        search = input ("Would you like to search by surname (S) or month of birth (M) ")

        if search.lower() == "s":
            surname = input ("Please enter the surname: ")
            for line in open("datafile.txt"):
                if surname in line:
                    print(line)


        elif search.lower() == "m":
            DMY = input("please enter your date of birth you are looking for (date/month/year) : ")
            DMY = DMY.split("/")
            DMY = DMY[1]

            for line in open("datafile.txt"):
                if DMY in line:
                    print(line)
        else:
            print ("Sorry you can not do this please try again.")
    elif yn == "n":
        print("Goodbye")
    else:
        print("Sorry you can not do this please try again.")
```

Comment: I think you need to be more specific... Can you define what you mean by "user friendly"?  What are you trying to achieve.  Clearer code?  Better end-user experience?  In what way do you feel the above is deficient?

Comment: If you are looking for fancier commandline UI, then check [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) or [urwid](http://urwid.org/)

Comment: Back in the 1970's this would have been considered quite user-friendly.

Comment: is that a complement?

Comment: That most likely is not complement. Also, downvote for this question, it should go to User Experience Stack Exchange: http://ux.stackexchange.com/ (downvote for offtopic, considering wrong domain of the question).

Comment: You might want: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try print("Welcome to the address book, This searches for a surname or address.")

Comment: thank you. you deserve a cookie

Comment: Just saw your question and you needed help so I helped

Comment: you are a good man sir